# Parsing XML file in oracle query

Tags: xml, oracle

My XML file looks like

```
<results>
<data><SearchIdType>HIST_ID</SearchIdType><SearchIdValue>3849183</SearchIdValue><ErrorCd>0</ErrorCd><SearchPayDate>2014-09-29T00:00:00Z</SearchPayDate><Searc
hTxTimestamp>2015-04-17T21:43:40.231Z</SearchTxTimestamp><ValidDate>2014-09-29T00:00:00Z</ValidDate><BondRuid>49223518</BondRuid><ProductClassificationType>I
ssue Type</ProductClassificationType><BondName>JPM 6.7 04/02/40</BondName><BaseCurrencyCode>USD</BaseCurrencyCode><IssueDate>2010-04-01T00:00:00Z</IssueDate>
<Rule144Indicator>N</Rule144Indicator><RegulationsIndicator>N</RegulationsIndicator><PrivatePlacementIndicator>N</PrivatePlacementIndicator><DtcEligibleIndic
ator>Y</DtcEligibleIndicator><DualCurrencyIndicator>N</DualCurrencyIndicator><SeniorRankIndicator>N</SeniorRankIndicator><JuniorRankIndicator>Y</JuniorRankIn
dicator><PerpetualMaturityIndicator>N</PerpetualMaturityIndicator><IssueAmount>60000000</IssueAmount><IssuePriceAmount>25</IssuePriceAmount><IssueOutstanding
Amount>60000000</IssueOutstandingAmount><SeriesDescription></SeriesDescription><MarketSectorCode>Pfd</MarketSectorCode><MininitialPurchaseNumber>25</Mininiti
alPurchaseNumber><MinIncrPurchaseNumber>25</MinIncrPurchaseNumber><CallableIndicator>Y</CallableIndicator><CalledDate></CalledDate><CalledPriceAmount></Calle
dPriceAmount><NextCallDate>2015-04-02T00:00:00Z</NextCallDate><NextCallPriceAmount>25</NextCallPriceAmount><NextParCallDate>2015-04-02T00:00:00Z</NextParCall
Date><MakeWholeCallIndicator>N</MakeWholeCallIndicator><SoftCallIndicator>N</SoftCallIndicator><FirstCallDate>2015-04-02T00:00:00Z</FirstCallDate><NextRefund
Date></NextRefundDate><PartialCallTypeCode></PartialCallTypeCode><PutableIndicator>N</PutableIndicator><NextPutDate></NextPutDate><NextParPutDate></NextParPu
tDate><NextPutPriceAmount></NextPutPriceAmount><FactorableIndicator>N</FactorableIndicator><NextFactorDate></NextFactorDate><PreviousReportedFactorRate>1</Pr
eviousReportedFactorRate><AnnounceDate>2010-03-25T00:00:00Z</AnnounceDate><FirstSettleDate>2010-04-01T00:00:00Z</FirstSettleDate><MaturityDate>2040-04-02T00:
00:00Z</MaturityDate><FinalMaturityDate>2040-04-02T00:00:00Z</FinalMaturityDate><BbgCalculationMaturityDate>2040-04-02T00:00:00Z</BbgCalculationMaturityDate>
</results>
```

This is just partial record, not full record

When I am trying to query the data using this file, it gives me parsing error.

> [Error] Execution (2: 17): ORA-31011: XML parsing failed ORA-19202:
>   Error occurred in XML processing LPX-00210: expected '=' instead of
>   '>' Error at line 3 ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 296 ORA-06512:
>   at line 1

Following is the query used: -

```
WITH t
     AS (SELECT xmltype (
                   BFILENAME ('GENIE_FEED_DIR', 'test_one_record.xml'),
                   NLS_CHARSET_ID ('UTF-8'))
                   xmlcol
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (x), '/results/data/SearchIdType')
          SearchIdType,
       EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (x), '/results/data/SearchIdValue')
          SearchIdValue,
       EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (x), '/results/data/ErrorCd')
          ErrorCd
  FROM t,
       TABLE (
          XMLSEQUENCE (
             EXTRACT (t.xmlcol, '/results/data'))) x;
```

Line 2 ending at     : `><Searc`

Line 3 starting from : `hTxTimestamp>2015-04-17T21:43:40.231Z</SearchTxTimestamp>`

How shall I query to parse such xml?

Answer (score 2):

If you'd formatted your xml correctly, you'd have quickly spotted that the issue is that you've missed out the closing data tag:

```
<results>
  <data>
    <SearchIdType>HIST_ID</SearchIdType>
    <SearchIdValue>3849183</SearchIdValue>
    <ErrorCd>0</ErrorCd>
    <SearchPayDate>2014-09-29T00:00:00Z</SearchPayDate>
    <SearchTxTimestamp>2015-04-17T21:43:40.231Z</SearchTxTimestamp>
    <ValidDate>2014-09-29T00:00:00Z</ValidDate>
    <BondRuid>49223518</BondRuid>
    <ProductClassificationType>Issue Type</ProductClassificationType>
    <BondName>JPM 6.7 04/02/40</BondName>
    <BaseCurrencyCode>USD</BaseCurrencyCode>
    <IssueDate>2010-04-01T00:00:00Z</IssueDate>
    <Rule144Indicator>N</Rule144Indicator>
    <RegulationsIndicator>N</RegulationsIndicator>
    <PrivatePlacementIndicator>N</PrivatePlacementIndicator>
    <DtcEligibleIndicator>Y</DtcEligibleIndicator>
    <DualCurrencyIndicator>N</DualCurrencyIndicator>
    <SeniorRankIndicator>N</SeniorRankIndicator>
    <JuniorRankIndicator>Y</JuniorRankIndicator>
    <PerpetualMaturityIndicator>N</PerpetualMaturityIndicator>
    <IssueAmount>60000000</IssueAmount>
    <IssuePriceAmount>25</IssuePriceAmount>
    <IssueOutstandingAmount>60000000</IssueOutstandingAmount>
    <SeriesDescription></SeriesDescription>
    <MarketSectorCode>Pfd</MarketSectorCode>
    <MininitialPurchaseNumber>25</MininitialPurchaseNumber>
    <MinIncrPurchaseNumber>25</MinIncrPurchaseNumber>
    <CallableIndicator>Y</CallableIndicator>
    <CalledDate></CalledDate>
    <CalledPriceAmount></CalledPriceAmount>
    <NextCallDate>2015-04-02T00:00:00Z</NextCallDate>
    <NextCallPriceAmount>25</NextCallPriceAmount>
    <NextParCallDate>2015-04-02T00:00:00Z</NextParCallDate>
    <MakeWholeCallIndicator>N</MakeWholeCallIndicator>
    <SoftCallIndicator>N</SoftCallIndicator>
    <FirstCallDate>2015-04-02T00:00:00Z</FirstCallDate>
    <NextRefundDate></NextRefundDate>
    <PartialCallTypeCode></PartialCallTypeCode>
    <PutableIndicator>N</PutableIndicator>
    <NextPutDate></NextPutDate>
    <NextParPutDate></NextParPutDate>
    <NextPutPriceAmount></NextPutPriceAmount>
    <FactorableIndicator>N</FactorableIndicator>
    <NextFactorDate></NextFactorDate>
    <PreviousReportedFactorRate>1</PreviousReportedFactorRate>
    <AnnounceDate>2010-03-25T00:00:00Z</AnnounceDate>
    <FirstSettleDate>2010-04-01T00:00:00Z</FirstSettleDate>
    <MaturityDate>2040-04-02T00:00:00Z</MaturityDate>
    <FinalMaturityDate>2040-04-02T00:00:00Z</FinalMaturityDate>
    <BbgCalculationMaturityDate>2040-04-02T00:00:00Z</BbgCalculationMaturityDate>
</results>
```

With the corrected xml, you should be using XMLTABLE to extract the information into columns (`EXTRACT` and `EXTRACTVALUE` are deprecated from 10g onwards), like so:

```
with t as (select xmltype('<results>
  <data>
    <SearchIdType>HIST_ID</SearchIdType>
    <SearchIdValue>3849183</SearchIdValue>
    <ErrorCd>0</ErrorCd>
    <SearchPayDate>2014-09-29T00:00:00Z</SearchPayDate>
    <SearchTxTimestamp>2015-04-17T21:43:40.231Z</SearchTxTimestamp>
    <ValidDate>2014-09-29T00:00:00Z</ValidDate>
    <BondRuid>49223518</BondRuid>
    <ProductClassificationType>Issue Type</ProductClassificationType>
    <BondName>JPM 6.7 04/02/40</BondName>
    <BaseCurrencyCode>USD</BaseCurrencyCode>
    <IssueDate>2010-04-01T00:00:00Z</IssueDate>
    <Rule144Indicator>N</Rule144Indicator>
    <RegulationsIndicator>N</RegulationsIndicator>
    <PrivatePlacementIndicator>N</PrivatePlacementIndicator>
    <DtcEligibleIndicator>Y</DtcEligibleIndicator>
    <DualCurrencyIndicator>N</DualCurrencyIndicator>
    <SeniorRankIndicator>N</SeniorRankIndicator>
    <JuniorRankIndicator>Y</JuniorRankIndicator>
    <PerpetualMaturityIndicator>N</PerpetualMaturityIndicator>
    <IssueAmount>60000000</IssueAmount>
    <IssuePriceAmount>25</IssuePriceAmount>
    <IssueOutstandingAmount>60000000</IssueOutstandingAmount>
    <SeriesDescription></SeriesDescription>
    <MarketSectorCode>Pfd</MarketSectorCode>
    <MininitialPurchaseNumber>25</MininitialPurchaseNumber>
    <MinIncrPurchaseNumber>25</MinIncrPurchaseNumber>
    <CallableIndicator>Y</CallableIndicator>
    <CalledDate></CalledDate>
    <CalledPriceAmount></CalledPriceAmount>
    <NextCallDate>2015-04-02T00:00:00Z</NextCallDate>
    <NextCallPriceAmount>25</NextCallPriceAmount>
    <NextParCallDate>2015-04-02T00:00:00Z</NextParCallDate>
    <MakeWholeCallIndicator>N</MakeWholeCallIndicator>
    <SoftCallIndicator>N</SoftCallIndicator>
    <FirstCallDate>2015-04-02T00:00:00Z</FirstCallDate>
    <NextRefundDate></NextRefundDate>
    <PartialCallTypeCode></PartialCallTypeCode>
    <PutableIndicator>N</PutableIndicator>
    <NextPutDate></NextPutDate>
    <NextParPutDate></NextParPutDate>
    <NextPutPriceAmount></NextPutPriceAmount>
    <FactorableIndicator>N</FactorableIndicator>
    <NextFactorDate></NextFactorDate>
    <PreviousReportedFactorRate>1</PreviousReportedFactorRate>
    <AnnounceDate>2010-03-25T00:00:00Z</AnnounceDate>
    <FirstSettleDate>2010-04-01T00:00:00Z</FirstSettleDate>
    <MaturityDate>2040-04-02T00:00:00Z</MaturityDate>
    <FinalMaturityDate>2040-04-02T00:00:00Z</FinalMaturityDate>
    <BbgCalculationMaturityDate>2040-04-02T00:00:00Z</BbgCalculationMaturityDate>
  </data>
</results>') xmlcol from dual)
select x.searchidtype,
       x.searchidvalue,
       x.errorcd
from   t,
       xmltable('/results/data'
                passing t.xmlcol
                columns SearchIdType varchar2(15) path 'SearchIdType',
                        SearchIdValue number path 'SearchIdValue',
                        ErrorCd number path 'ErrorCd') x;

SEARCHIDTYPE    SEARCHIDVALUE    ERRORCD
--------------- ------------- ----------
HIST_ID               3849183          0
```